# Listing all the files under a directory recursively, using Pipes

Tags: haskell, recursion, directory, haskell-pipes

I finished reading the [Pipes tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.3/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), and I wanted to write a function to list all the files in a directory, recursively. I tried with the following code:

```
enumFiles :: FilePath -> Producer' FilePath (PS.SafeT IO) ()
enumFiles path =
  PS.bracket (openDirStream path) (closeDirStream) loop
  where
    loop :: DirStream -> Producer' FilePath (PS.SafeT IO) ()
    loop ds = PS.liftBase (readDirStream ds) >>= checkName
      where
        checkName :: FilePath -> Producer' FilePath (PS.SafeT IO) ()
        checkName ""   = return ()
        checkName "."  = loop ds
        checkName ".." = loop ds
        checkName name = PS.liftBase (getSymbolicLinkStatus newPath)
                         >>= checkStat newPath
          where newPath = path </> name

        checkStat path stat
          | isRegularFile stat = yield path >> loop ds
          | isDirectory stat = enumFiles path
          | otherwise = loop ds
```

However this producer will terminate as soon as the `return ()` is reached. I guess I'm not composing it in the right way, but I fail to see what is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
| isDirectory stat = enumFiles path
```

to

```
| isDirectory stat = enumFiles path >> loop ds
```

The code was missing the recursion in this recursive case.

You can also break this producer up into a composition of smaller producers and pipes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Main where

import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.Safe as PS

import           Control.Monad
import           Pipes
import           System.FilePath.Posix
import           System.Posix.Directory
import           System.Posix.Files

readDirStream' :: FilePath -> Producer' FilePath (PS.SafeT IO) ()
readDirStream' dirpath =
  PS.bracket (openDirStream dirpath) closeDirStream (forever . loop)
  where
    loop stream =
      liftIO (readDirStream stream) >>= yield

enumFiles :: FilePath -> Producer' FilePath (PS.SafeT IO) ()
enumFiles path =
  readDirStream' path
    >-> P.takeWhile (/= "")
    >-> P.filter (not . flip elem [".", ".."])
    >-> P.map (path </>)
    >-> forever (do
                    entry <- await
                    status <- liftIO $ getSymbolicLinkStatus entry
                    when (isDirectory status) (enumFiles entry)
                    when (isRegularFile status) (yield entry))

main :: IO ()
main =
  PS.runSafeT $ runEffect (enumFiles "/tmp" >-> P.stdoutLn)
```

I find it's often helpful to use `forever` from `Control.Monad` or one of the combinators from `Pipe.Prelude` instead of manual recursion; it helps cut down on small typos like this one. However, as the kids say, your mileage may very well vary.

Comment: I haven't thought about de-composing the problem as you did. Very nice. Probably this is a question for another SO question, but with this approach we might reach the limit of open directories since we're visiting them in a depth first search order, right?

Comment: @DamianNadales I don't think directories work like that. You don't open one and get a handle to it and use that like a cursor to list its contents . You just have a file path and make a syscall that gives you a list of the contents of that path at the time the syscall was made.

Comment: I thought I was using the directory stream as a cursor, since I'm opening it, and iterating through its contents using: `readDirStream stream`...